# Error while building Passthrough stream org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPProcessingException: First Element must contain the local name, Envelope

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

**Scenario**
I've developed a scheduled task that runs after every 30 seconds. The task is injected to a proxy service. The proxy service implements a sequence which calls the HTTP Address and further dumps the data into postgresdb

**Task**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<task class="org.apache.synapse.startup.tasks.MessageInjector" group="synapse.simple.quartz" name="IoscoScheduledTask" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <trigger interval="100"/>
    <property name="message" xmlns:task="http://www.wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks">
        <alert>dataDumped</alert>
    </property>
    <property name="injectTo" value="proxy" xmlns:task="http://www.wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks"/>
    <property name="proxyName" value="alertsIoscoProxy" xmlns:task="http://www.wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks"/>
</task>
```

**Proxy Service**
Proxy service uses sequence which basically send HTTP Call to the URL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy name="alertsIoscoProxy" startOnLoad="true" transports="http https" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <sequence key="IoscoSequence"/>
            <log level="full"/>
            <property description="conversion" name="XML2JSON" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
            <propertyGroup description="Alert">
                <property expression="json-eval($.alerts.alert.id)" name="id" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                <property expression="json-eval($.alerts.alert.datePosted)" name="datePosted" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                <property expression="json-eval($.alerts.alert.company)" name="company" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                <property expression="json-eval($.alerts.alert.regulator)" name="regulator" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                <property expression="json-eval($.alerts.alert.jurisdiction)" name="jurisdiction" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                <property expression="json-eval($.alerts.alert.link)" name="link" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                <property expression="json-eval($.alerts.alert.subject)" name="subject" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                <property expression="json-eval($.alerts.alert.comments)" name="comments" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                <property expression="json-eval($.alerts.alert.attachments)" name="attachments" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            </propertyGroup>
            <dataServiceCall description="Data" serviceName="Data">
                <operations type="batch">
                    <operation name="addAlert">
                        <param name="id" value="property_value"/>
                        <param name="datePosted" value="property_value"/>
                        <param name="company" value="property_value"/>
                        <param name="regulator" value="property_value"/>
                        <param name="jurisdiction" value="property_value"/>
                        <param name="link" value="property_value"/>
                        <param name="subject" value="property_value"/>
                        <param name="comments" value="property_value"/>
                        <param name="attachments" value="property_value"/>
                    </operation>
                </operations>
                <source type="inline"/>
                <target type="body"/>
            </dataServiceCall>
            <log level="full"/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <respond/>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence>
            <log/>
        </faultSequence>
    </target>
</proxy>
```

**Data Service**

```
<data transports="http https local" serviceGroup="" serviceNamespace="" name="IoscoDataService">
  <description />
  <config id="postgres">
    <property name="driverClassName">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres</property>
    <property name="username">postgres</property>
    <property name="password">xxxx</property>
  </config>
  <query id="addAlertQuery" useConfig="postgres">
    <sql>INSERT INTO public."IOSCO_RESPONSE"
("ID", "DATE_POSTED", "COMPANY", "REGULATOR", "JURISDICTION", "LINK", "SUBJECT", "COMMENTS", "ATTACHMENTS")
VALUES(:id, :datePosted, :company, :regulator, :jurisdiction, :link, :subject, :comments, :attachments);
</sql>
    <param type="IN" name="company" paramType="SCALAR" sqlType="STRING" optional="false" />
    <param type="IN" name="regulator" paramType="SCALAR" sqlType="STRING" optional="false" />
    <param type="IN" name="jurisdiction" paramType="SCALAR" sqlType="STRING" optional="false" />
    <param type="IN" name="link" paramType="SCALAR" sqlType="STRING" optional="false" />
    <param type="IN" name="subject" paramType="SCALAR" sqlType="STRING" optional="false" />
    <param type="IN" name="comments" paramType="SCALAR" sqlType="STRING" optional="false" />
    <param type="IN" name="attachments" paramType="SCALAR" sqlType="STRING" optional="false" />
    <param type="IN" name="id" paramType="SCALAR" sqlType="STRING" optional="false" />
    <param type="IN" name="datePosted" paramType="SCALAR" sqlType="STRING" optional="false" />
  </query>
     <operation name="addAlert" returnRequestStatus="true">
      <call-query href="addAlertQuery">
         <with-param name="id" query-param="id"/>
         <with-param name="datePosted" query-param="datePosted"/>
         <with-param name="company" query-param="company"/>
         <with-param name="regulator" query-param="regulator"/>
         <with-param name="jurisdiction" query-param="jurisdiction"/>
         <with-param name="link" query-param="link"/>
         <with-param name="subject" query-param="subject"/>
         <with-param name="comments" query-param="comments"/>
         <with-param name="attachments" query-param="attachments"/>
      </call-query>
   </operation>
     <resource method="POST" path="/Alert">
      <call-query href="addAlertQuery">
      <with-param name="id" query-param="id"/>
         <with-param name="datePosted" query-param="datePosted"/>
         <with-param name="company" query-param="company"/>
         <with-param name="regulator" query-param="regulator"/>
         <with-param name="jurisdiction" query-param="jurisdiction"/>
         <with-param name="link" query-param="link"/>
         <with-param name="subject" query-param="subject"/>
         <with-param name="comments" query-param="comments"/>
         <with-param name="attachments" query-param="attachments"/>
      </call-query>
   </resource>
</data>
```

**Sample Data from URL**

```
<alerts>
<message>Results are capped at 500 records.</message>
<alert>
<id>22847</id>
<datePosted>20221118</datePosted>
<company>GreatInvest (Clone of FCA authorised firm)</company>
<regulator>Financial Conduct Authority</regulator>
<jurisdiction>United Kingdom</jurisdiction>
<link>https://www.fca.org.uk/news/warnings/greatinvest-clone-fca-authorised-firm</link>
<subject>Regarding fraudulent or manipulative practices (insider dealing, market manipulation, misrepresentation of material information, etc.)<br /><br />Regarding registration of issuance, offer or sale of securities/derivatives, and reporting requirements<br /><br />Regarding market intermediaries (investment and trading advisers, collective investment schemes, brokers, dealers, and transfer agents)<br /><br />Regarding markets, exchanges, and clearing and settlement entities<br /><br />Miscellaneous</subject>
<comments/>
<attachments/>
</alert>
</alerts>
```

**ERROR**

```
 INFO {LogMediator} - {proxy:alertsIoscoProxy} To: , MessageID: urn:uuid:3054d6d1-553c-4c42-a58d-370408943766, Direction: request
[2022-11-20 21:15:42,800] ERROR {RelayUtils} - Error while building Passthrough stream org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPProcessingException: First Element must contain the local name, Envelope , but found alerts
        at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.constructNode(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:305)
        at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.createOMElement(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:252)
        at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.createNextOMElement(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:234)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:249)
        at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.getSOAPEnvelope(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:204)
        at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.<init>(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:154)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.AbstractOMMetaFactory.createStAXSOAPModelBuilder(AbstractOMMetaFactory.java:73)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.AbstractOMMetaFactory.createSOAPModelBuilder(AbstractOMMetaFactory.java:79)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.OMXMLBuilderFactory.createSOAPModelBuilder(OMXMLBuilderFactory.java:196)
        at org.apache.axis2.builder.SOAPBuilder.processDocument(SOAPBuilder.java:65)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.DeferredMessageBuilder.getDocument(DeferredMessageBuilder.java:153)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:169)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:122)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.util.PassThroughMessageHandler.buildMessage(PassThroughMessageHandler.java:103)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.doSOAPFormatConversion(Axis2Sender.java:412)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendBack(Axis2Sender.java:193)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.RespondMediator.mediate(RespondMediator.java:46)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:110)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:72)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:377)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:627)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:208)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:298)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

**Sequence**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="IoscoSequence" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <log level="full"/>
    <call>
        <endpoint>
            <address format="get" statistics="enable" trace="enable" uri="https://www.XXXX.XXX/investor_protection/investor_alerts/xml-feed">
                <suspendOnFailure>
                    <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
                    <progressionFactor>-1</progressionFactor>
                    <maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration>
                </suspendOnFailure>
                <markForSuspension>
                    <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
                </markForSuspension>
            </address>
        </endpoint>
    </call>
</sequence>
```

**Question**
My question is: why proxy service is considering the HTTP response as SOAP and throws SOAPProcessingError while clearly the response is Rest with XML data formatting?. How can I resolved this issue?

Comment: your proxy calls a sequence that you don't show yet that seems to do some interesting things. I think the error might be caused there. Can you share the "IoscoSequence" here as well?

Comment: it simply calls the http endpoint, that's pretty much it

Comment: @ophychius i dont understand what code changes have you suggested?

Comment: @AyubJamal What do you see for the log ` <log level="full"/>` after dataServiceCall mediator? Also, Since you are invoking the service through a task do you want to send the Dataservice response back to the caller?

Comment: @ycr No actually, I just want to bulk insert the data

Answer (score 0):

Before your `Respond` mediator set the following properties.

```
<outSequence>
    <property name="messageType" value="application/xml" scope="axis2"/>
    <property name="ContentType" value="application/xml" scope="axis2"/>
    <respond/>
</outSequence>
```

Comment: I've added these properties but the error still persist

Comment: I think proxy service is considering the request as soap while its just the plain xml, which don't have envelope tags.

Comment: @AyubJamal What is the `Content-Type` your service provider is sending with this payload?

Comment: The error seems to be in the parsing of the response from the dataservice. So setting these on the out sequence  won't do much afaik.

Comment: @sonoJ its text/xml

Comment: @ophychius if you look closely at the shared Stacktrace the error is originated from the `Respond` mediator which is in the `Outsequence`. That's why I suggested adding them there before the Respond mediator.

Comment: @AyubJamal can you share the `IoscoSequence` as well?

Comment: @sanoJ I've updated the question, please find the sequence there

Answer (score -1):

According to the error:

What is missing is the  tag

Try adding this before the Alerts, as this is SOAP it puts the Envelope with the namespaces.

```
<soap:envelope
xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/"
soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding">
<alerts>
....
</alerts>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: I cant do that, since xml isnt in our control. The service provider has this fix format

Comment: The most correct thing is to create a Proxy Service in your environment that uses the provider's service that you have no control over.

Thus, you use your local service (the way you want) that connects to the provider's service already with the necessary transformation.


Local Proxy -> Provider Proxy

Task -> Local Proxy -> Provider Proxy